# Arduino interrupt output compare register not working as expected

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to use interrupts to toggle a pin with Arduino Uno. This is what I have so far:

```
const int outputPin = 12;

void setup() {
    pinMode(outputPin, OUTPUT);
    // initialize Timer0
    noInterrupts(); // disable all interrupts

    TCCR0A = 0;
    TCCR0B = 0;
    TCNT0 = 0;

    OCR0A = 255;
    TCCR0B |= (1 << WGM12); // CTC mode
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS12); 
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS10); // 1024 prescaler
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // enable timer compare interrupt
    interrupts(); // enable all interrupts
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){
  digitalWrite(outputPin,digitalRead(outputPin)^1); //Toggle pin
}
```

I am using an oscilloscope to read the voltage on the pin and when I change the value of OCR0A there is no change. I am not sure why nothing is changing. I would like to also add that there are no errors.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, You mix TIMER0 ports and TIMER1 bits constants, use WGM0x, CS0x and so on. You try to set CTC mode like TIMER1. For TIMER0 set bit WGM01 of TCCR0A port:

```
TCCR0A  = 1 << WGM01;
TCCR0B  = 1 << CS02 | 1 << CS00;
OCR0A   = <Max counter value>;

TIMSK0 |= 1 << OCIE0A;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however when I change the value of OCR0A the period on the oscilloscope does not change, and so my problem persists.